# I am not able to set the footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

my code https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wencl2ca7u0vy5t/AABksofzqJsAfIpAVb0IdcN5a?dl=0

please help me, I have been studying HTML since 3 weeks and CSS since a week on codecademy so sorry if you find some stupid code. If you see that I can improve my code somewhere else, feel free to tell me your changes!

If you open the link that I attached there is a folder with everything inside. I chose this option rather than provide only a sample of code because all the solutions that I found for this problem didn't work in my case.

The only way that solved my case is to set a relative position to the footer and move it with top and right properties. The problem is that if I do that when somebody zooms the screen the footer doesn't appear well in the web page. Thank you in advance.

I wasn't aware that dropbox doesn't show the code for the index so here it is the code of index.html:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resources/css/index.css">

<title>Colmar Academy</title>
```

```
<header class="first_container">

    <div class="second_container">

        <figure>

            <img class="logo" src="../resources/images/ic-logo.svg" alt=""/>

        </figure>

        <h1><strong>COLMAR</strong>ACADEMY</h1>

    </div>

    <nav>

        <ul>

            <li><a href="#">On Campus</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Online</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Companies</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>

        </ul>

    </nav>

</header>

<!-- 3rd container (banner) with "learn something new everyday" -->

<main>

    <div class="third_container">

        <figure>

            <img src="../resources/images/banner.jpg" alt=""/>

        </figure>

        <div class="learn">

            <h1 class="learn">Learn something<br>new everyday</h1>

            <h3 class="learn">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br>consectetur adipiscing elit.</h3>

            <h3 class="start"><a href="#">Start here</a></h3>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- middle of the page (orientation date, campus) -->

    <!-- left side -->

    <div class="fourth_container">

        <figure>

            <img src="../resources/images/information-main.jpg" alt=""/>

        </figure>

        <div>

            <h3 class="practicing">It doesn't hurt to keep practicing</h3>

            <p>

                "Curabitur vitae libero in ipsum porttitor consequat. Aliquam et commodo lectus,<br>nec consequat neque. Sed non accumsan urna. 
                Phasellus sed consequat ex. Etiam<br>eget magna laoreet, efficitur dolor consequat, tristique ligula."

            </p>

            <br><br>

            <aside>Emanuel, Sr Strategist at Hiring.com</aside>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- end of left side -->

    <!-- right side -->
    
    <div class="side">

        <figure>

            <img src="../resources/images/information-orientation.jpg" alt=""/>
        
        </figure>

        <figure>

            <img src="../resources/images/information-campus.jpg" alt=""/>

        </figure>

        <figure>

            <img src="../resources/images/information-guest-lecture.jpg" alt=""/>
        
        </figure>

    </div>
    
    <div class="side_two">

        <h3>Orientation Date</h3>

        <h4>Tue 10/11 & Wed 10/12: 8am-3pm</h4>

        <a class="read_more" href="#">Read more</a>

        <h3 class="side_three">Our Campus</h3>
        
        <h4>Find which campus is close by you</h4>

        <a class="read_more" href="#">Read more</a>

        <h3 class="side_three">Our guest lecture</h3>

        <h4>Join a keynote with Oliver Sack<br>about music in medical treatment</h4>
        
        <a class="read_more" href="#">Read more</a>

    </div>

    <!-- end of right side -->

    <!-- setting up 6 containers inside another one (Start Learning) -->
    
    <div class="fifth_container">

        <h1 class="learning">Start learning</h1>

        <div class="inside_container1" id="more_margin">
            
            <figure>

                <a href="#"><img src="../resources/images/course-software.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                    
            </figure>

            <h3>Software engineering</h3>

            <h4>COURSES</h4>
            
            <h4>Web Development, Mobile<br>Development, iOT, APIs</h4>

        </div>

        <div class="inside_container" id="more_margin">

            <figure>

                <a href="#"><img src="../resources/images/course-computer-art.jpg" alt=""/></a>
            
            </figure>

            <h3>Computer art</h3>

            <h4>COURSES</h4>

            <h4>Imaging & Design, Web Design,<br>Motion Graphics & Visual Effects,<br>Computer Animation</h4>

        </div>
        
        <div class="inside_container2" id="more_margin">

            <figure>

                <a href="#"><img src="../resources/images/course-design.jpg" alt=""/></a>

            </figure>

            <h3>Design</h3>

            <h4>COURSES</h4>
            
            <h4>User Experience Design, User<br>Research, Visual Design</h4>
                
        </div>

        <div class="inside_container1" id="more_margin_bottom">

            <figure>

                <a href="#"><img src="../resources/images/course-data.jpg" alt=""/></a>
            
            </figure>

            <h3>Data</h3>

            <h4>COURSES</h4>

            <h4>Data Science, Big Data, SQL, Data<br>Visualization</h4>
                
        </div>

        <div class="inside_container" id="more_margin_bottom">

            <figure>

                <a href="#"><img src="../resources/images/course-business.jpg" alt=""/></a>

            </figure>

            <h3>Business</h3>

            <h4>COURSES</h4>

            <h4>Product Development, Business<br>Development, Startup</h4>
                
        </div>

        <div class="inside_container2" id="more_margin_bottom">

            <figure>

                <a href="#"><img src="../resources/images/course-marketing.jpg" alt=""/></a>

            </figure>

            <h3>Marketing</h3>

            <h4>COURSES</h4>

            <h4>Analytics, Content Marketing,<br>Mobile Marketing</h4>
                
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Thesis exhibit (left side) -->

    <h1 class="thesis">Thesis exhibit</h1>
        
    <div class="left_side">

        <video src="../resources/videos/thesis.mp4" controls>Video not supported</video>

        <div class="last_container">
        
            <h3>Reimagine urban</h3>

            <p>

                "Curabitur vitae libero in ipsum porttitor consequat. Aliquam et commodo lectus, 
                nec<br>consequat neque. Sed non accumsan urna. Phasellus sed consequat ex. Etiam eget<br>magna laoreet, 
                efficitur dolor consequat, tristique ligula."

            </p>

        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Thesis exhibit (right side) -->

    <div class="right_side">

        <figure>

            <a href="#"><img src="../resources/images/thesis-fisma.jpg" alt=""/></a>

        </figure>

        <figure>

            <a href="#"><img src="../resources/images/thesis-now-and-then.jpg" alt=""/></a>

        </figure>
        
    </div>
    
    <div class="right_side2">

        <h3>Fisma: Design and<br>Prototype</h3>

        <h4>Designer showcase of new<br>prototype product</h4>

        <h3 id="now">Now and then</h3>

        <h4>Research study about New York</h4>

    </div>

    <!-- end of thesis -->

</main>

<footer class="css-footer">

    <h4>Colmar Academy. All right reserved</h4>

    <a href="#">Terms</a>

    <a href="#">Privacy</a>

</footer>
```

I was able to do it by making 2 containers

```
<footer class="footer_container">

    <h4>Colmar Academy. All rights reserved</h4>

    <div class="footer_2_container">

        <a href="#">Terms</a>

        <a href="#">Privacy</a>

    </div>

</footer>
```

and then I added this to the css

.footer_2_container, .footer_2_container a {

```
color: darkslategray;
text-decoration: none;
margin-right: 10px;
```

}

.footer_container {

```
display: inline-flex;
width: 100%;
justify-content: space-between;   
margin-top: 150px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
```

}

.footer_container h4 {

```
font-weight: normal;
margin-left: 20px;
```

}

Comment: please provide code example

Comment: If you open the link that I attached there is a folder with everything inside. I chose this option rather than provide only a sample of code because all the solutions that I found for this problem didn't work in my case. Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a style attribute to the footer, i.e:

```html
<!-- Your HTML here -->

<footer style="">
  <p>Your content here</p>
</footer>
```

Or add a class to the footer (recommended), i.e:

```html
<footer class="footer-css">
  <p>Your content here</p>
</footer>
```

If you added the style attribute, type this inside it:

```css
padding: 10px; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 0px;
```

What does it mean?

padding: 10px; means that the space between the content of the footer and the borders of the documents will be 10 pixels

text-align: center; means that the content of the footer will be centered

margin-bottom: 0px; means that the space between the padding of the footer and the bottom of the page will be zero pixels

If you added a class, you should have a styles.css file linked to the html index. In the CSS file type this:

```css
# note: replace the following css-footer with the class that you assigned to the footer

.css-footer {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Hope it helped you, bye and good luck!

Comment: I already tried this solution yesterday and it didn't work. I tried again this morning by copying and pasting your code and the footer is still on the middle of the page :( Thank you for your answer!

Comment: I recommend you using Bootstrap or W3CSS then. https://getbootstrap.com | https://w3schools.com/w3css

Comment: Hi fabio, thank you for your answer. I would like to solve the issue by improving my code and not follow a scheme already set by somebody else and do every single project with that scheme

Comment: I agrree, try assigning a 'position: relative;' to body, a 'position:absolute;' to the footer and play and the top and bottom values, you can use positive and negative numbers.

Comment: I solved the issue (answer in my question). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple to put footer at bottom if you are a bit familiar with CSS `position` property. Just specify the following in your CSS-

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

The above is the example if you want it to be fixed at a place, but if you just want it to be at the bottom of the page then, use the following-

```
footer {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't want it to be fixed. I already tried (and again right now) margin-bottom: 0 but it didn't work. :( Thank you for your answer!